# Create a long panel data set in R

Tags: r, regression, panel-data

I got a dataset of companies with monthly return. I want to do a MacBeth-Regression with `pgm` (from package `plm`). But first I need to transform my set into paneldata.
I tried `panel_data(xsr, id= 'Company Name', wave= 'Dates')` but it didn't work, since there are several columns which already have the ticker of the companies.
Then I tried to transpose the set and do it with `long_panel(xsrt, begin = 40209, end = 41670 )`.

I'm bit confused since I got no column with all the names listed and I don't want to copy paste every thing to get a long dataset.
The read dataset looks like this: [image]

and has 144 observations and 245 variables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reshape Panel Data Wide Format to Long Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004399/reshape-panel-data-wide-format-to-long-format)

Comment: There are plenty of questions with answers for how to reshape a panel data set in wide format to long format - did you try the hints from these? Furhter, it is not clear where functions `panel_data` and `long_panel` stem from.